# How to check whether the user has for the first time on a certain route? Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular

is there a way that I only know on the angular that the user is on a route for the first time?

I want to show the modal if the user is on that route for the first time and I know how to display the modal but I don't know exactly how to track when it is on the route for the first time  I was thinking local storage but it's also temporary ..

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?
is it even possible to do this without a backend?

Comment: You can use a client cookie if you don't want to rely on backend.

Comment: How to do it? Can you provide me any tutorial or what ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use client cookies using [ngx-cookie-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service).

In your route page component, you check if the cookie exists on the client with:
`const cookieExists: boolean = this.cookieService.check('yourCookieName');`
If it's false, you display your modal.
On your modal closeEvent, you set up the cookie:
`this.cookieService.set( 'yourCookieName', 'true');`

The cookie value is not very important here since you just want to know if it exists. There's also optional parameters you can provide to the set method, like the expiration date, the path, the domain, a secured flag and the sameSite token to prevent cross-site request with this cookie.